# Pop up image on click - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have HTML code like below:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="pic-profile" id="">
   <img src="http://oi66.tinypic.com/r8b8g0.jpg" alt="" id="">
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is a profile pic and when I click on it, I want to open it like it happens in Whatsapp.

How can I do that? Not sure If I should use fancybox or something like that?

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oapsvebf/1/).

Comment: See if [Modal Images](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) are what you are looking for.

Comment: Use j query .you can fancybox. It will solve you problem http://fancybox.net/

Comment: I am trying to use prettyphoto, another plugin but getting the 

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function
** error

Comment: Try FancyBox,its simple and jquery inbuilt

Comment: But Its paid now so....

Answer (score 0):

Please refer for the fiddle just as sample.You can add many options in the j query from the fancy box API. Please use two type images one big and another small so that the bigger image will come on click of smaller image. Hope this will help you.